# How can select data from parent and all type of child tables in one LINQ query?

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api

I have a parent table and several child tables whose structure differs from each other. Child tables has a parent table key as foreign key with one to one relationship. At one time parent table has only one child and other child tables are null. Can I assemble a query that gets all the data from parent table and all child tables with all additional columns?

I'm using below code but it has many queries and this is not good for me, so I want to assemble these queries into one.

```
(from reward in entities.REWARDS

where reward.Fk_BrandId_Reward == brandId && reward.RewardStatus == true

orderby reward.RewardRedemption ascending
select new
{
    reward.RewardId,
    reward.RewardImage,
    reward.RewardTitle,
    reward.RewardDescription,
    reward.TYPE.Title,
    reward.RewardRedemption,
    reward.RewardStatus,
    reward.RewardExpireInDays,
    reward.RewardValidFrom,
    reward.RewardValidTo,
    reward.RewardDeductionPoints,
    reward.RewardIsIsSignUpBonus,
    reward.RewardIsTiered,
    reward.RewardTierIncrement,
    reward.Fk_BrandId_Reward,

    Type = (from type in entities.TYPES
            where type.Id == reward.FK_RewardTypeId
            select new
            {
                type.Id,
                type.Title
            }).FirstOrDefault(),

    Schedule = (from schedule in entities.SCHEDULES
                where schedule.FK_RewardId == reward.RewardId
                select new
                {
                    schedule.Id,
                    schedule.FromWeekDay,
                    schedule.FromMonthDate,
                    schedule.FromAnnualDate,
                    schedule.ExpireInDays,
                    schedule.FK_RewardId
                }).FirstOrDefault(),

    ItemReward = (from item in entities.ITEMS
            where item.FK_RewardId == reward.RewardId
            select new
            {
                item.Id,
                item.RewardDiscount,
                item.FK_RewardId,
                Product = (from product in entities.PRODUCTS
                            where product.ProductId == item.FK_ProductId
                            select new
                            {
                                product.ProductId,
                                product.ProductTitle,
                                product.ProductOldPrice,
                                product.ProductNewPrice,
                                product.ProductImageUrl,
                                product.ProductContent,
                                product.ProductCategory,
                                product.ProductSubCategory,
                                product.ProductPostedTime,
                                product.ProductStocks,
                                product.ProductStatus,
                                product.FK_BrandId_Products
                            }).FirstOrDefault(),

                Recipe = (from recipe in entities.RECIPEs
                            where recipe.RecipeId == item.FK_RecipeId
                            select new
                            {
                                recipe.RecipeId,
                                recipe.RecipeImage,
                                recipe.RecipeTitle,
                                recipe.RecipeDescription,
                                recipe.RecipePrice,
                                recipe.RecipeStatus,
                                recipe.RecipePostTime,
                                recipe.RecipeStock,
                                recipe.CATEGORY.CategoryTitle,
                                recipe.FK_BrandId_Recipes,
                                recipe.RecipeExtraObject
                            }).FirstOrDefault()

            }).FirstOrDefault(),

    CashReward = (from cash in entities.CASHes
                        where cash.FK_RewardId == reward.RewardId
                        select new
                        {
                            cash.Id,
                            cash.RewardCash,
                            cash.FK_RewardId
                        }).FirstOrDefault(),

    PointReward = (from point in entities.POINTS
                        where point.FK_RewardId == reward.RewardId
                        select new
                        {
                            point.Id,
                            point.RewardPoints,
                            point.FK_RewardId
                        }).FirstOrDefault(),

    DeliveryReward = (from delivery in entities.DELIVERies
                where delivery.FK_RewardId == reward.RewardId
                select new
                {
                    delivery.Id,
                    delivery.RewardDiscount,
                    delivery.FK_RewardId
                }).FirstOrDefault()

}).ToList();
```

Any one has batter idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which end database you are using? Have you checked what queries are getting generated?

Comment: @SushantYelpale I'm using sql server database.

Comment: have you checked queries generated in sql server profiler?

Comment: no, when i run my existing code i can see result on browser in json. That is okay but i want to assemble these queries into one.